# Scale a vector with chosen mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, scale

I have a `vector` with 100 elements.
I am trying to scale it with a mean of 2 and a sd of 3.

something like:

```
Vector_scaled = scale(vector, mean = 2, sd = 3)
```

I don't find an efficent way or a build in function to do it.

Comment: there is the `scale`-function in R. It's arguments are `center=` and `scale=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @humpelstielzchen pointed aready in the comments there is the functions `scale`. To scale `vector` to a mean of 2 and a sd of 3 you can use:

```
vector <- 1:100

vector <- scale(vector)*3+2

mean(vector) #2
sd(vector)   #3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using mtcars data set

```
mtcars$mpg-mean(mtcars$mpg)+2
```

for mean 2

```
mtcars$mpg/sd(mtcars$mpg)*3
```

for sd 3